# The expected value of the sum of random variables of random length.

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, martingales

Suppose, we first roll an $N$-sided dice and let $X$ be the respective random variable. Next, we roll $X$ times an $X$-sided dice. Let $Y_1,\dots,Y_X$ be the respective random variables of the respective dice rolls.

**Question:** Is there a way to simplify the expected value of the sum $\sum_{i=1}^X Y_i$?

According to [Wald's equality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%27s_equation), if $X$ is independent of the sequence $Y_1,Y_2,\dots$, then we get
$E[X]\cdot E[Y]$ as the answer. However, in the scenario I'm describing there is a dependency between $X$ and $Y_1,\dots,Y_X$.

Comment: Hint: Find  $E[\sum Y_i \mid X]$.  It should be related to $X^2$ and $X$.  So $E[E[\sum Y_i \mid X]]$ should be related to  $E[X^2]$ and $E[X]$, each of which you can find in terms of $N$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, the faces of the $X$ sided die are represented by the elements in the set $\{1, 2, \ldots, X\}$. Therefore, the average roll of an $X$ sided die is

$$\frac{X+1}{2}.$$

So, if you roll an $X$ sided die $X$ times, you should expect the sum of the $X$ rolls to be

$$X \cdot \frac{X+1}{2}.$$

The simplest resolution is to forgo any elegance or heavy machinery (i.e. theorems).

Simply assume that the *experiment* is done $N$ times, with the first roll taking on each of the numbers in the set $\{1,2,\ldots,N\}$. Therefore, the expected value of the sum is

\begin{align*}
&\frac{1}{N} \cdot \left[ \, \sum_{X=1}^{N} \left( X \cdot \frac{X + 1}{2} \right) \, \right] \\
&\hspace{1.5em} = \frac{1}{2N} \cdot \left[ \, \left( \sum_{X=1}^{N} X^2 \right) + \left( \sum_{X=1}^{N} X \right) \, \right].
\end{align*}

Note that

$$ \sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = \frac{n^3}{3} + \frac{n^2}{2} + \frac{n}{6} \hspace{1.5em}\text{and}\hspace{1.5em} \sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac{n^2}{2} + \frac{n}{2}.$$

Comment: Thanks! Suppose I wanted to use heavy machinery for simplifying $E\big[ \sum_{i=1}^X Y_i\big]$, where the $Y_i$ are i.i.d., and the distribution of $Y_i$ depends on $X$. Are there any theorems I should look at?

Comment: @Arun Beats me.  My knowledge of Probability theory is very limited (**and superficial**).  I attacked this problem only because it didn't really require any knowledge of Probability Theory (AKA Theorems).